# Clear individual text box in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with the ten text boxes. I have a submit button too. I would like to clear, two text box in row on click of a button in html.

Below is the screen shot:

[image]:

CODE:

```
 <form action="store_number.php" method="POST" name="myform" class="addform" div id="container" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Number Details</legend><br>
    <div class="fieldwrapper">
    <div class="thefield">   
    <input type="text" class="hint" id="name1" onkeypress='validate1(event)' value="<?php echo $namearray[0];?>" onfocus="if (this.className=='hint') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.className = 'hint'; this.value = '<?php echo $namearray[0];?>';}" size="25" name="name1" maxlength="30"/>   <input type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)' class="hint" id="number1" value="<?php echo $numberarray[0];?>"  onfocus="if (this.className=='hint') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.className = 'hint'; this.value = '<?php echo $numberarray[0];?>';}" size="20" name="number1" maxlength="10"/> <img src="img/clear.png" width="24" height="24"></a> </div>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
 <p align="center">
 <div class="buttonsdiv">
 <p align="center">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" id="submit" class="button1" />
 </div>

 </form>
```

When I click on the red cross button for a particular row, I would like get to name and number textbox to have value Name and Number.

I tried to submit button button but then it is clashing with the FORM. Reset doesn't work too.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by markup?

Comment: @TheDevMan he means source code

Comment: Add your Html to question so we could help you write selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept, even though it's rather ugly and bloated, it gets the job done.
There are prettier ways to solve this, but this one should be easy to understand:

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKtmh

```
<input type="text" id="1a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="1b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('1a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('1b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('1a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('1b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="2a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="2b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('2a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('2b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('2a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('2b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="3a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="3b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('3a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('3b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('3a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('3b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="4a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="4b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('4a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('4b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('4a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('4b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="5a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="5b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('5a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('5b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('5a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('5b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="6a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="6b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('6a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('6b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('6a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('6b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="7a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="7b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('7a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('7b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('7a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('7b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="8a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="8b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('8a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('8b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('8a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('8b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="9a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="9b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('9a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('9b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('9a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('9b').value='Number'))};"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="10a" value="Name"/><input type="text" id="10b" value="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="x" onclick="if ((document.getElementById('10a').value!='Name') || (document.getElementById('10b').value!='Number')) {((document.getElementById('10a').value='Name') && (document.getElementById('10b').value='Number'))};"/>
```

PS: You should use an ID that doesn't start with a number. HTML validators may not like it.

Comment: Thanks this works for me put my OnFocus goes aways. When I onFocus on TextBox. The hint text gets blank. Now I have to do a back space and then type. Any idea on how to solve that issue

Comment: Yeah. Which I already implemented in my code. Shown above in my question, but when I use the X button the onFocus part doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without the actual HTML, but assuming your code looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"><input type="text"><button>X</button>
</div>
```

You'll probably want to add a listener `<button onclick="clearRow(this)">` and a JS function to clear the input fields:

```
function clearRow(button) {
    var inputs = button.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    inputs[0].value = 'Name';
    inputs[1].value = 'Number';
}
```

Edit: You added your HTML code. Just attach the listener to your `<img>` tag.

Edit2: I can't seem to find the beginning of that `<a>` tag in that one long line. You may have to adapt the first line of `clearRow` to account for further nesting of the "X button".

Answer (score -1):

Assumin that your HTML is something like that :

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="name-1" class="nameInput">   
        <input type="text" name="number-1" class="numberInput">   
        <button class="cross"> X </button>   
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="name-1" class="nameInput">   
        <input type="text" name="number-1" class="numberInput">   
        <button class="cross"> X </button>   
    </div>
</form>
```

If you want to use jQuery; this will do the job :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.cross').click(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent('dv');
        $parent.find('input.nameInput').val('Name');
        $parent.find('input.numberInput').val('Number');
    })
});
```

Comment: He did not ask for jQuery

Comment: I thought any fast solution would be useful as he didn't specify

Comment: jQuery is not a fast solution and it does not help learning JavaScript and understanding DOM manipulations.

Comment: I totally agree with; When using jQuery a lot, you forget about the basic javascript